# Django include template

Tags: django, django-templates

The [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include) states that includes are rendered with their own variables and settings.

I have a big template that consists of a lot of widgets, which, for better structure i would like to have each in its own file.

For this I'm using the *include* template tag, which in this scenario has two drawbacks:

1. Pass every template variable from the parent template to the include tag
2. Load the whole set of template tags and filter within each included template

This is not DRY and probably bad for performance as well.

Is there a better practice to do this?

Edit:
1. all the variables are passed from the parent, which makes the which statement kind of redudant.

Comment: As far as I remember the 'root' template variables are available in includes by default, no need to explicitly pass them.

Comment: True, so its just about loading the template tags then

Comment: The amount of time it takes to render additional templates is pretty minimal. You can test this pretty easily by using `time.time()` and `render` to render each template ~100,000 times, then compare the two average times.